Which languages, other than French, show a habit of trying not to repeat the same word too soon in writing?
I have learnt French, so I am somewhat familiar with that tendency.
But still, reading this headline I randomly came across just now, that tendency struck me even more.
Botswana menace d'offrir 20 000 éléphants à l'Allemagne pour illustrer la difficulté de cohabiter avec le pachyderme
Now, there is no way that any English-speaking news editor would bother to look up an alternative word as a placeholder for "elephant", least of all an obscure Greek word like pachyderm.
Does any other language you know share this feature - a reluctance to use the same word twice in close proximity in writing?
Does it have anything to do with the degree of interchangeability that words are perceived to have in a language?

I don't know, I definitely think an English headline writer would try to avoid repeating "elephant", they'd just go for a simpler word like "them"

It's a stylistic matter, not one of the language itself. Of course some languages are more suited for that than others: in English you have a lot of near-synonyms, so i's easier not to repeat yourself. But in principle it's purely stylistic.

For normal people in normal speech, this is what pronouns are for.  ... avec eux.   This is about headlines by headline writers vs. normal speech by normal people, not French vs other languages.

Who says an editor “look[ed] up an alternative word as a placeholder”? Even as a non-specialist, I’m aware that animals like elephants, hippos and rhinos are pachyderms – I would expect a journalist who’d been researching for and writing a story about them would know this too and just use the word naturally. Note that the word is also used further down in the text (“C'est un tiers de la population mondiale de pachydermes et elle a plus que doublé en 30 ans”).

@JanusBahsJacquet Although that term has been obsolete for some time... As another non-specialist in classification of mammals, I am glad to have not heard this term myself.

@Arfrever It’s obsolete as a taxonomical order; it’s not obsolete as a regular word referring loosely to large land animals with thick skin.

Oliver is right. It is a fact that in France when they teach you to write, they eschew repetition of words in close proximity. This is an excellent example of that. It is a style thing in French writing. Especially for expository writing. As a foreigner who studied at a French university, this was emphasized all the time by everyone. Professors and students alike. English is not as sensitive in this regard. You often get the repetition of the word in the next sentence. In French, they bend over backwards to avoid that...

@Lambie In Italian it's the same as in French (sometimes to almost humorous extent in the newspaper, where they use some ridiculously archaic words to avoid repetition).

@DenisNardin That should be a reply.

@DenisNardin I'm not sure any of this is really "linguistics" at all.

We learnt it in Czech class, so I would say its more like case of a standard langue. The question is if you are refering to natural or standardize phenomena then. Because such standard could be in various languages to make the language from an artifical scientific point of view nicer.
